# May have made a mistake... before I reboot help me out

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have ubuntu 18.04 installed and I recently bought a second 64 GB SSD I wanted to install windows on.

1) I powered off the machine, connected the drive, and see it in fdisk -l and saw my drive was `/dev/sdd`

2) I ran `fdisk /dev/sdd` and hit `d` for delete partition to remove anything

3) I then hit `g` to create a new GPT table

4) I hit `w` to my changes and i get this message :

```
Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Failed to remove partition 1 from system: Device or resource busy

The kernel still uses the old partitions. The new table will be used at the next reboot. 
Synching disks.
```

am i going to have issues on next reboot? my base os is EXT4  on an SSD and I have 3 hdd in ZFS ?

the only thing I wanted to do is install my windows iso on this disk... I'm assuming i'm going in the right direction however i'm afraid to reboot my box now.

would `sudo dd if=<ISO_FILE> of=/dev/sd<DRIVE_ID>` have worked? would it have been bootable?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and be more specific.  "My drive"  = new or existing?  Where is your base OS installed?  `/dev/sda1`?  where are the other HDDs located?  Now your question is unanswereable without more details. Also, please limit your question to... well... one question.  **;-) 0:-)**

Comment: Base os I installed in /dev/sda goal is to have a Windows drive ready to boot..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify, then leave another comment, please.